# Setuptools how to package just some modules and files

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'm packaging a little python package. I'm a complete newbie to python packaging, my directory structure is as follows (up to second level nesting):

```
.
├── data
│   ├── images
│   ├── patches
│   └── train.csv
├── docker
│   ├── check_gpu.py
│   ├── Dockerfile.gcloud_base
│   ├── Dockerfile.gcloud_myproject
├── env.sh
├── gcloud_config_p100.yml
├── legacy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── notebooks
│   └── mypackage
├── notebooks
│   ├── EDA.ipynb
│   ├── Inspect_patches.ipynb
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── create_patches_folds.py
│   └── create_patches.py
├── setup.py
├── mypackage
    ├── data
    ├── img
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── jupyter
    ├── keras_utils
    ├── models
    ├── train.py
    └── util.py
```

My setup.py:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    "h5py==2.9.0",
    "numpy==1.16.4",
    "opencv-python==4.1.0.25",
    "pandas==0.24.2",
    "keras==2.2.4",
    "albumentations==0.3.1"
]

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(include=["mypackage.*"]),
    include_package_data=False
)
```

The code i want to package corresponds only to the mypackage directory. That's why i passed "mypackage.*" to find_packages and used include_package_data=False.

If i run:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

All project structure gets packaged in the resulting tar.gz file.

Anyone knowing how to just package modules inside mypackage/ and the top level README file? I'm not finding this in setuptools docs.

Comment: The directory tree doesn't show any `mypackage`. Please [edit] and either fix the name or fix the tree.

Comment: Done, thank you. Obviously that directory is a package and not a module, just a typo when i obfuscated my real package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to fix is

```
packages=find_packages(include=["mypackage"]),
```

But you also need to understand that `sdist` is mostly controlled by the files [`MANIFEST` or its template `MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest), not `setup.py`. You can compare what is created with `sdist` and `bdist_wheel` or `bdist_egg`; content of `bdist_*` is controlled by `setup.py`.

So my advice is to create the following `MANIFEST.in`:

```
prune *
include README.txt
recursive-include mypackage *.py
```

Comment: MANIFEST.in is what i'm trying right now, and i came up with a similar solution. I think the 'legacy/' dir is included because it happens to contain a "mypackage" package also. But what about docker/? It contains just a single .py file which is not in any of the included packages... Anyway, i'm currently developing a proper MANIFEST.in, i'll mark your reply as the answer later today, thank you.

Comment: Just another question: Why you say the packages=find_packages(include=["mypackage"]), needs to be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: You only have one package `mypackage`. Try `find_packages(include=["mypackage"])` and `find_packages(include=["mypackage.*"])` from the command line.